# JavaMailSender failure: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing '"'

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

We have a [JavaMailSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html) which failed on `send()`.

This usually works well for us for quite a long time. Only now we have a peculiar bug:

JavaMailSender failure: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing '"'

This is the code:

```
public class MailService {
    private static JavaMailSender fooMailSender;

    ...

    class FooSendMail extends Thread {
        MimeMessage message;

        FooSendMail(MimeMessage message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                fooMailSender.send(message);
            } catch (MailException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a stack trace of the error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing '"'; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing '"'
    at javax.mail.internet.HeaderTokenizer.readQuotedString(HeaderTokenizer.java:272)
    at javax.mail.internet.HeaderTokenizer.readToken(HeaderTokenizer.java:134)
    at javax.mail.internet.HeaderTokenizer.next(HeaderTokenizer.java:81)
    at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.<init>(ParameterList.java:68)
    at javax.mail.internet.ContentDisposition.<init>(ContentDisposition.java:51)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:580)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:128)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:1353)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:443)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at com.builde.service.MailService$FooSendMail.run(MailService.java:434)
```

We couldn't understand what the problem was.

The question is: what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

We found out that attaching a *.msg (Outlook message file) was causing the problem.

It could be that JavaMailSender doesn't support *.msg attachments